# How to cut out parts of string after certain characters

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a list of domains joined in a string like this:

```
"example.comsuper.comregular.comextraordinary.comhello.com"
```

I need a JS function to take a string like this as an input and return me an array something like this:

```
["example.com", "super.com", "regular.com", "extraordinary.com", "hello.com"]
```

You can assume ".com" is what always signals to "cut" nothing else.

Thank you!

Comment: Can we always assume `.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression

```js
console.log(
  "example.comsuper.comregular.comextraordinary.comhello.com".match(/\w+.com/g)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to split by `/(?<=(com))/` and `filter` out odd indexes

```
var output = "example.comsuper.comregular.comextraordinary.comhello.com".split(/(?<=(com))/).filter( (s,i) => i % 2 == 0);
```

**Demo**

```js
var regex = /(?<=(com))/;

var input = "example.comsuper.comregular.comextraordinary.comhello.com";

var output = input.split( regex ).filter( (s,i) => i % 2 == 0);

console.log( output );
```